# Not able to query a Hive table where data is stored as sequencefile format, where data is coming from HBASE export utility

Tags: hive, export, hbase

I exported datasets from **HBASE** to **HIVE** via `export` utility. Data is coming as sequence file format.
Now, I am creating a hive table with `"stored as sequencefile"`.

When I am doing simple, select query with limit on the hive table, i am getting the below exception

**java.io.IOException: Could not find a deserializer for the Value class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured,**

Detailed error trace below:

> Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=0,
>   operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True,
>   modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0,
>   operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='\xb2\x9a^\xc5\xc5\xf3BV\xb1\xb8\xe7\xb6\xab\xe7f\xc0',
>   guid='\xca\x0c\xc9\\xc0%@\xb4\xa1{\xe4\xc7\xaa(;\xcb')),
>   orientation=4, maxRows=100):
>   TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0,
>   errorMessage="java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Could not find
>   a deserializer for the Value class:
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the
>   configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're
>   using custom serialization.", sqlState=None,
>   infoMessages=["*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:java.io.IOException:
>   java.io.IOException: Could not find a deserializer for the Value
>   class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the
>   configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're
>   using custom serialization.:14:13",
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:366',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:277',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:753',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:438',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:686',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1553',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1538',
>   'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
>   'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor:process:HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:746',
>   'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142',
>   'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617',
>   'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745',
>   "*java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: Could not find a
>   deserializer for the Value class:
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the
>   configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're
>   using custom serialization.:18:4",
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:508',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:pushRow:FetchOperator.java:415',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask:fetch:FetchTask.java:138',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:getResults:Driver.java:1798',
>   'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:361',
>   "*java.io.IOException:Could not find a deserializer for the Value
>   class: 'org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result'. Please ensure that the
>   configuration 'io.serializations' is properly configured, if you're
>   using custom serialization.:26:8",
>   'org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader:init:SequenceFile.java:2040',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader:initialize:SequenceFile.java:1878',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader::SequenceFile.java:1827',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader::SequenceFile.java:1841',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader::SequenceFileRecordReader.java:49',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat:getRecordReader:SequenceFileInputFormat.java:64',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator$FetchInputFormatSplit:getRecordReader:FetchOperator.java:674',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getRecordReader:FetchOperator.java:324',
>   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:446'],
>   statusCode=3), results=None, hasMoreRows=None)